# ansible read part of xml as string - not as dict / list

Tags: xml, ansible

I have a below mentioned xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`  
<Envelope>  
  <Body>  
    <response>  
      <timestamp>2018-11-01T15:18:44-04:00</timestamp>  
      <content>`  
        <element1>value1</element1>  
        <element2>value2(/element2>  
        <element3>  
          <child1>c1</child1>  
          <child2>c2</child2>  
        </element3>  
      </content>  
    </response>  
  </Body>  
</Envelope>
```

I have to capture the `content` tag children in xml format only to encode it.

when I use xml module to get the content and its descendants, captured as list of dictionaries.

All I want is I should capture the `content` as a string like

```
"<element1>value1</element1>  
 <element2>value2(/element2>  
 <element3>  
      <child1>c1</child1>  
      <child2>c2</child2>  
 </element3>"
```

as a string.
Later I will use this string to encode and decode.

I do not want to encode each and every descendant of `content`, but all the `content` together.

How can I achieve this using ansible. 
I am using ansible version 2.4

Comment: I may open a new question, but wanted to ask you how you read a part of a xml into a dictionary (your content section)? I just don't get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off reading the [Ansible xml module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/xml_module.html), it doesn't seem possible.

You can use the `command` module using a utility like `xmllint` to do it like this:

```
---
- name: run the playbook tasks on the localhost
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Get Content Section
    command: "xmllint --xpath '/Envelope/Body/response/content' --format test.xml"
    register: out

  - name: output
    debug:
      msg: "{{ out.stdout }}"
```

Which would look like so:

```
PLAY [run the playbook tasks on the localhost] ***************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [Get Content Section] ***********************************************************************************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [output] ************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "<content><element1>value1</element1><element2>value2</element2><element3><child1>c1</child1><child2>c2</child2></element3></content>"
}

PLAY RECAP     ***************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that to even use `xml:` the **target** python must be available (and have the `lxml` egg/wheel installed, but we won't need it for this purpose):

```
  vars:
    name_of_the_xml_file: whatever-filename
  tasks:
  - command: '{{ ansible_python_interpreter }} -u - {{ name_of_the_xml_file }}'
    args:
      stdin: |
        import sys
        from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse, tostring
        with open(sys.argv[1]) as fh:
            doc = parse(fh)
        c = doc.find('.//content')
        print(tostring(c))
    register: the_content
  - debug: var=the_content.stdout
```