# Ansible - save part of xml-file in dictionary

Tags: xml, ansible

I am trying to save a part of a xml-file in a dictionary in ansible.
It's related (quite the opposite) to this question, but that doesn't solve my problem: [ansible read part of xml as string - not as dict / list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234342/ansible-read-part-of-xml-as-string-not-as-dict-list)

So i have a xml-file like:

```
<domain xmlns="http://x.com"
  <deployment>
    <name>
    </name>
    <notes>
    </notes>
  </deployment>
  <deployment>
    <name>
    </name>
    <notes>
    </notes>
  </deployment>
  <deployment>
    [...]
  </deployment>
</domain>
```

My task looks like this:

```
- name: read config.xml
  xml: 
    path: config.xml
    xpath: //xmlns:domain/xmlns:deployment
    namespaces:
      xmlns: http://x.com
    content: text
  register: deployments
```

I want to have the deployment sections in a list or dictionary to loop them and read all notes for example. But i just don't get it work. With the above task the output (`-debug: var: deployments`) is just a '\n', but not the following tags with their content.

One further note: When I run the task with `count: yes` it recognizes the right amount of deployment sections, so i would expect it to get stored as a list.

I tried various things with the [xml module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/xml_module.html), but would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: I can't tell if that is really the code you are using, but `xmlns=` is a magic attribute which defines the [default XML namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting), and thus your `//xmlns:domain` is highly unlikely to do anything good. Try switching it to `ns0:domain` and `namespaces:\n  ns0: http://x.com` type deal

Comment: It certainly appears that `xml: content=text` is not designed to capture _elements_ but only text (or attributes) within the document. Are you expecting `deployments` to contain the element `<deployment>` and its children?

Comment: I just used xmln as variable, but you are right - to make sure there are no sideeffects, i changed it.

Comment: And yes, i want `deployments` to contain the element(s) `<deployment>` and its children. Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: Then what's wrong with the **very answer you linked to**? Separately, what are you going to the items in `deployments` after you get them, because it's super likely that you are solving the wrong problem

Comment: I thought it would be possible to get the xml-structure **directly into an ansible-dictionary**. But yes, you may be right with that linked answer. I'm now writing my own module - to get used to python and ansible and to satisfy my needs ;) thank you anyway!

Comment: @Maik did you find a way to do so ?

Comment: @XeniaIoannidou I actually wrote my own module to process the xml-File the way I needed it.

Comment: @Maik is your code for this task available ?

Comment: @XeniaIoannidou I'm sorry, but I wrote the code at work, so it can't be published.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote my own module to process the xml-File the way I needed it.
Sorry @Admin, wrong Button. Should have been a comment...